# Create a stock Ledger Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create stock ledger from this table.

[image]

and I want to get a result like this.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Pictures are not helpful for sample data. [Forum Etiquette: How to provide Sample data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: Add actual table structure with sample data and expected results. That will give more clarity.

Comment: How do you know what the `Stock Date` is from your source table?

Comment: Stock date already in the source table

Comment: Not in the one you have included in your question.  Please ensure ***all*** relevant information is in your question.  We do not have access to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a running balance of each product in each warehouse, this should get you started on how to achieve what you want.  If you need to aggregate across the products and warehouses in a different way, I will leave that for you to figure out.

---

The key part here is the use of the `order by` in the `over` windowed function clause.  What this does is `sum` all rows up to the current on, in `InvoiceDate` order:

```
declare @t table(InvoiceDate date,InvoiceNo nvarchar(20),ProductId int,WareHouseId int,StockIn int, StockOut int);
insert into @t values('20180211','11218',2,2,100,0),('20180301','march18',1002,2,30,0),('20180701','july2018',1003,2,50,0),('20180701','july2018',1002,2,100,0),('20180301','SI-00001',1002,2,0,20),('20180301','SI-00002',1002,2,0,5),('20180317','20180317',1003,3009,50,0),('20180317','20180317',1010,3009,30,0),('20180317','20180317',1012,3009,25,0),('20180301','SI-18-03-1',1002,3009,0,20),('20180301','ST-18-03-01',1003,3009,50,0);

select t.WareHouseId
    ,t.InvoiceNo
    ,t.ProductId
    ,t.StockIn
    ,t.StockOut
    ,sum(t.StockIn) over (partition by t.WareHouseID, t.ProductId order by t.InvoiceDate, t.InvoiceNo)
    -sum(t.StockOut) over (partition by t.WareHouseID, t.ProductId order by t.InvoiceDate, t.InvoiceNo) as Balance
from @t as t
order by t.WareHouseId
        ,t.ProductId
        ,t.InvoiceDate
        ,t.InvoiceNo;
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+
| WareHouseId |  InvoiceNo  | ProductId | StockIn | StockOut | Balance |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+
|           2 | 11218       |         2 |     100 |        0 |     100 |
|           2 | march18     |      1002 |      30 |        0 |      30 |
|           2 | SI-00001    |      1002 |       0 |       20 |      10 |
|           2 | SI-00002    |      1002 |       0 |        5 |       5 |
|           2 | july2018    |      1002 |     100 |        0 |     105 |
|           2 | july2018    |      1003 |      50 |        0 |      50 |
|        3009 | SI-18-03-1  |      1002 |       0 |       20 |     -20 |
|        3009 | ST-18-03-01 |      1003 |      50 |        0 |      50 |
|        3009 | 20180317    |      1003 |      50 |        0 |     100 |
|        3009 | 20180317    |      1010 |      30 |        0 |      30 |
|        3009 | 20180317    |      1012 |      25 |        0 |      25 |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+----------+---------+
```